# Scrapy creating XML feed wraps content in "value" tags

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I've had a bit of help on here by my code pretty much works. The only issue is that in the process of generating an XML, it wraps the content in "value" tags when I don't want it to. According to the doc's this is due to this:

> Unless overriden in the :meth:`serialize_field` method, multi-valued
>   fields are    exported by serializing each value inside a `<value>`
>   element. This is for    convenience, as multi-valued fields are very
>   common.

This is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <body>
         <value>Don't forget me this weekend!</value>
      </body>
      <to>
         <value>Tove</value>
      </to>
      <who>
         <value>Jani</value>
      </who>
      <heading>
         <value>Reminder</value>
      </heading>
   </item>
</items>
```

What I send it to the XML exporter seems to be this, so I don't know why it think's it's multivalue?

```
{'body': [u"Don't forget me this weekend!"],
 'heading': [u'Reminder'],
 'to': [u'Tove'],
 'who': [u'Jani']}
```

pipeline.py

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class XmlExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

spider.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from crawler.items import CrawlerItem

class SiteSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'site'
    allowed_domains = ['www.w3schools.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml']
    itertag = 'note'

    def parse_node(self, response, selector):
        item = CrawlerItem()
        item['to'] = selector.xpath('//to/text()').extract()
        item['who'] = selector.xpath('//from/text()').extract()
        item['heading'] = selector.xpath('//heading/text()').extract()
        item['body'] = selector.xpath('//body/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I just want the same output without the redundant  tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extract()` method will always return a list of values, even if there is only a single value as a result, for example: `[4]`, `[3,4,5]` or `None`.
To avoid this, if you know there is only one value, you can select it like:

```
item['to'] = selector.xpath('//to/text()').extract()[0]
```

Note:
Be aware that this can result in an exception thrown in case `extract()` returns `None` and you are trying to index that. In such uncertain cases, this is a good trick to use:

```
item['to'] = (selector.xpath('...').extract() or [''])[0]
```

Or you could write your custom function to get the first element:

```
def extract_first(selector, default=None):
    val = selector.extract()
    return val[0] if val else default
```

This way you can have a default value in case your desired value is not found:

```
item['to'] = extract_first(selector.xpath(...))  # First or none
item['to'] = extract_first(selector.xpath(...), 'not-found')  # First of 'not-found'
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct regarding why this is happening, but I'd like to add that there is now out of the box support for this, and no need to write a helper method.

```
item['to'] = selector.xpath('//to/text()').extract_first()
```

and

```
item['to'] = selector.xpath('//to/text()').extract_first(default='spam')
```